# How get pusher events when the iOS app go to the background?

Tags: ios7, background, pusher

I need to get triggered eventos from pusher, and when the app go the background I don't get them (only the first one).

I have this:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) PTPusherPresenceChannel *taxi_channel;

PTPusherPresenceChannel *taxi = [PusherController sharedApp].taxi_channel;

- (void)viewDidLoad

@weakify(self);

[taxi bindToEventNamed:@"client-driver-cancel-service" handleWithBlock:^(PTPusherEvent *event)
 {
     DDLogDebug(@"%@: %@", event.name, event.data);
     @strongify(self);

     [self cancelServiceAcepted];
 }];
```

The problem is that I get a single event when get into the background, but after the first I don't get them anymore.

I have implemented the code at https://github.com/pusher/pusher-test-iOS/blob/master/Diagnostics/Code/ClientDisconnectionHandler.h

If the app go the foreground it work fine.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of libPusher. I answered your question on Github but I thought I'd post it here as it might be helpful for others.

Unfortunately its not really possible to use Pusher in the background and its not really what it is designed for. Pusher works great for receiving events in realtime while your app is running but to get background notifications, you really need to be looking at using Apple push notifications OR period fetch, depending on whether you'd prefer push or pull.

My suggestion would be:

- Use Pusher while your app is in the foreground to receive real-time updates
- Use push notifications to send significant events to your app while it is in the background (these should be less frequent) AND/OR
- Possibly use background fetch to pull the latest changes/events from your server
- Restart listening to events from Pusher when your app resumes in the foreground

Comment: Is there a way to let a user stay 'online' when in background? Should we ping our server within a timeinterval to let back end know we are online? Maybe it's just not a good idea to let a user stay online when in background